# Reduce Array Elements (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have this collection

```
{ 
    "branchName" : "Branch1", 
    "products" : [
        {
            "name" : "Chocolate", 
            "quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "price" : "64"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Torta Galaxy", 
            "quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "price" : "30"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Torta Chocolate", 
            "quantity" : NumberInt(1), 
            "price" : "91"
        }
}
```

I want to output like

```
BranchName, name, quantity, price, subtotal
Branch1, Chocolate, 2, 64, 128
Branch1, Torta Galaxy, 2, 30, 60
Branch1, Torta Chocolate, 1, 91, 91
```

The problem is to project array elements rows in results as I couldn't do it by project. So that I could make arithmetic operation on these values like sum or multiply

Answer (score 0):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `products` array field to multiple documents.
2. `$project` - Display document in the desired output format.

   For `subtotal` field, convert `product.price` to decimal (`$toDecimal`) and next `$multiply` with `product.quantity`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "branchName": "$branchName",
      "name": "$products.name",
      "quantity": "$products.quantity",
      "price": "$products.price",
      "subtotal": {
        "$multiply": [
          "$products.quantity",
          {
            "$toDecimal": "$products.price"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TPPvVN12ZZy)